# Characteristic subgroup of an Abelian-by-Finite Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a group such that $A$ is a normal Abelian subgroup and $G/A$ is finite. Is always possible to find an Abelian characteristic subgroup $B$ such that $G/B$ is finite too?

Factoring by $G^n$ where $n=|G/A|$ we can reduce ourselves to the case in which $G$ has finite exponent. Therefore $A$ is a direct sum of cyclic subgroups. But then? Is it possible to continue?

Comment: What do you mean by $G^n$ ?

Comment: The subgroup generated by elements like $g^n$ with $g\in G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I completely misread the question. For some reason I thought you wanted $B \le A$. Let's try again. I think the answer is yes.

Let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by all images of $A$ under automorphisms of $G$. Then $G:H$ is finite and $H\ {\rm char}\ G$.

But, since $H:A$ is finite, $H$ must be generated by finitely many of the images $A_1,\ldots,A_k$ of $A$ under automorphisms of $G$. The intersection $\cap_{1 \le i \le k} A_i$has finite index in $H$ and is centralized by all $A_i$ and hence by $H$. Then $Z(H)\ {\rm char}\ H\ {\rm char}\ G$, so we can take $B=Z(H)$.

Comment: Don't worry! Now the thing look more clear to me. Thanks!